# Is using Delphi 10.3 components in a Delphi 2007 project even possible. are there workarounds?

Tags: delphi

Im currently assigned with finding a way of making toast notifications work in delphi 2007. Doing this in the latest version is easy but our desktop application is based on delphi 2007.The .pas files are filled with syntax the 2007 version is unfamiliar with. Is this even feasible. What options are available to me? Sorry if this seems an uninformative question. Im a relatively new programmer and i have no idea in which direction i should be looking. Thank you!

Comment: No, but you can wrap the necessary interfaces yourself in D2007 to use notifications. I did that with the TaskBar interfaces to be able to provide animated progress on task bar buttons. It's typically not that difficult.

Comment: The only other alternative is to wrap the newer Delphi code in a DLL and then call that from the D2007 project.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to create a D2007 wrapper to the API